# how to create an object with only filtered content in PHP OOP

Tags: php

I have created a class with constructor in php which filter xml file. But the object created take all xml data. How can I avoid that?

Thank you for your help!

My code:

```
class  Property {
    public $xmlClass;
    public $elemClass = '';
    public $result_array = [];
    public $data = '';

    public function __construct($xml,$elem) {
        $this->xmlClass=$xml;
        $this->elemClass=$elem;

        foreach($xml->list->movie as $value) {
            $data = $value->$elem;
            $result_array[] = $data;
        }

        print_r($result_array);                   //here everything is ok
    }
}

$result_title = new Property('title');
print_r($result_title);    //here object takes all data, not only filtered
```

Comment: `$result_title` is an object with a lot of props. `$result_array` is a list of your filtered data. Currently there're __no connection__ between them.

Comment: So you mean I have to use arrow somehow? I suppose $result_title grabs everyting, xml database and filtered data. I really doubt if there is any solution to continue this code or basicaly my knowledge in oop is too little

Comment: Yes, This is the way I was searching whole day. Thank you so much, you are my hero ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result_title` is an **object** with a lot of props. Among them there's your initial `xml` as you assign it to `xmlClass` property.

To get the desired data you need to store it in a class property, you already declare it (`$result_array`).

So, a proper code could be:

```
class  Property {
    public $xmlClass;
    public $elemClass = '';
    public $result_array = [];
    public $data = '';

    public function __construct($xml,$elem) {
        $this->xmlClass=$xml;
        $this->elemClass=$elem;

        foreach($xml->list->movie as $value) {
            $data = $value->$elem;
            // add data to a class property `result_array`
            $this->result_array[] = $data;
        }
    }

    // get value of `result_array` with this method
    public function getResultArray() 
    {
        return $this->result_array;
    }
}

$result_title = new Property('title');
print_r($result_title->getResultArray());
```

Comment: The problem is now for me, the keys of arrays created are always "0", Strange, and very unusefull.  I have now json which have every keys: "0". Is there any hope for this code?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is these two lines:

```
    $this->xmlClass=$xml;
    $this->elemClass=$elem;
```

You are assigning them to the object. You can just save the `result_array` to a property of the object and access that:

```
class  Property {
    public $xmlClass;
    public $elemClass = '';
    public $result_array = [];
    public $data = '';

    public function __construct($xml,$elem) {
        $this->xmlClass=$xml;
        $this->elemClass=$elem;

        foreach($xml->list->movie as $value) {
            $data = $value->$elem;
            $result_array[] = $data;
        }

        $this->titles = $result_array); 
    }
}

$object = new Property('title');
print_r($object->titles);
```